# OpenCV + QML (grabbing frame from another thread)

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, opencv, qml

I have a problem to read OpenCv Mat  from other thread  and display it in QML.

Firstly I create Mat in other thread  and prevent update it until QML will not display it:

```
void DesktopVideoProducer::process(){
    while(true){
        if(!camera.isOpened())
        camera.open("http://192.168.43.1:8080/video");
        camera >> mat;
        if(!frameReady && !mat.empty()){
        outMat =  cv::Mat(10, 10, 1);
        qDebug() << "!!!! = " << outMat.data;
        frameReady = true;
        }
    }
}
```

In `qDebug() << "!!!! = " << outMat.data;` I see that outMat has data `!!!! =  0x38824980`

Here I try to display this Mat in QML:

```
void DesktopVideoProducer::timerEvent(QTimerEvent*)
{
    if (!_surface) return;

    if(frameReady)
    qDebug() << "ddd = " << outMat.data;

    if(frameReady && !outMat.empty())
    {
            cv::cvtColor(outMat, outMat, cv::COLOR_BGR2BGRA);

            QImage screenImage((uchar*)outMat.data, outMat.cols, outMat.rows, outMat.step, QImage::Format_RGB32);

            if(QSize(winWidth, winHeight) != _format.frameSize())
            {
                qDebug() << "newSize";
                closeSurface();
                _format = QVideoSurfaceFormat( QSize(winWidth, winHeight), QVideoFrame::PixelFormat::Format_RGB32);
                _surface->start(_format);
            }

            _surface->present( QVideoFrame( screenImage ) );

            frameReady = false;
    }
}
```

But when I try to read Mat here:

```
if(frameReady)
    qDebug() << "ddd = " << outMat.data;
```

it show that no data in this outMat: `ddd =  0x0`

And I can't to display no one frame from another thread.
Here is my code:

DesktopVideoProducer.h

```
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QAbstractVideoSurface>
#include <QVideoSurfaceFormat>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QTime>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

class DesktopVideoProducer : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY( QAbstractVideoSurface* videoSurface READ videoSurface WRITE setVideoSurface )
public:
    explicit DesktopVideoProducer( QObject *parent = 0 );
    ~DesktopVideoProducer();

    QAbstractVideoSurface* videoSurface() const;
    void setVideoSurface( QAbstractVideoSurface* s );
    void Initialization();

public slots:
void timerEvent(QTimerEvent*);

private:
    void closeSurface();

private:
    QAbstractVideoSurface* _surface;
    QVideoSurfaceFormat _format;
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    cv::VideoCapture camera;
    cv::Mat mat;
    cv::Mat outMat;
    QImage screenImage;
    void process();
};
```

DesktopVideoProducer.cpp

```
#include "DesktopVideoProducer.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtConcurrent/QtConcurrent>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QMutex>

QMutex mutex;
int winWidth, winHeight;
bool isInit = false;
bool frameReady = false;

DesktopVideoProducer::DesktopVideoProducer( QObject *parent )
    : QObject( parent ), _surface(nullptr)
{
    startTimer(1000 / 15); //15 fps
}

DesktopVideoProducer::~DesktopVideoProducer()
{
    closeSurface();
}

QAbstractVideoSurface* DesktopVideoProducer::videoSurface() const
{
    return _surface;
}

void DesktopVideoProducer::Initialization(){
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:///main.qml")));

    QtConcurrent::run(this, DesktopVideoProducer::process);

    winWidth = engine.rootObjects()[0]->property("width").toInt();
    winHeight = engine.rootObjects()[0]->property("height").toInt();
}

void DesktopVideoProducer::process(){

    while(true){
        if(!camera.isOpened())

        camera.open("http://192.168.43.1:8080/video");

        camera >> mat;

        if(!frameReady && !mat.empty()){
        outMat =  cv::Mat(10, 10, 1);
        qDebug() << "!!!! = " << outMat.data;
        frameReady = true;

        }
    }
}

void DesktopVideoProducer::setVideoSurface( QAbstractVideoSurface* s )
{
    closeSurface();
    _surface = s;
}

void DesktopVideoProducer::closeSurface()
{
    if( _surface && _surface->isActive() )
        _surface->stop();
}

void DesktopVideoProducer::timerEvent(QTimerEvent*)
{
    if (!_surface) return;

    if(frameReady)
    qDebug() << "ddd = " << outMat.data;

    if(frameReady && !outMat.empty())
    {
            cv::cvtColor(outMat, outMat, cv::COLOR_BGR2BGRA);

            QImage screenImage((uchar*)outMat.data, outMat.cols, outMat.rows, outMat.step, QImage::Format_RGB32);

            if(QSize(winWidth, winHeight) != _format.frameSize())
            {
                qDebug() << "newSize";
                closeSurface();
                _format = QVideoSurfaceFormat( QSize(winWidth, winHeight), QVideoFrame::PixelFormat::Format_RGB32);
                _surface->start(_format);
            }

            _surface->present( QVideoFrame( screenImage ) );

            frameReady = false;
    }
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

#include"DesktopVideoProducer.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    qmlRegisterType<DesktopVideoProducer>("DesktopVideoProducer", 0, 1, "DesktopVideoProducer");

    DesktopVideoProducer videoProvider;

    videoProvider.Initialization();

    return app.exec();
}
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.1
import QtMultimedia 5.0
import DesktopVideoProducer 0.1

Window {
    visible: true
    visibility: "Maximized"
    id: root

    DesktopVideoProducer {
        id: videoProducer;
    }

    VideoOutput {
        anchors.fill: parent
        source: videoProducer;
    }
}
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code is likely incorrect and implies the source overridden while conversion performed:

```
cv::cvtColor(outMat, outMat, cv::COLOR_BGR2BGRA);
```

The conversion should me more like:

```
cv::Mat outFrame;
cvtColor(inFrame, outFrame, conversionType); // cvtColor makes copy
```

Comment: Of course it may worth the debug session etc. but the purpose of SO is in finding coding advise. Try some working example and run it and start modifying it bit by bit, I guess. `QtConcurrent` is maybe not needed here. It is not a massive parallel processing. Use `QThread`.

Comment: Really, I found that this method `cv::Mat outFrame;
cvtColor(inFrame, outFrame, conversionType);` work faster than this `cv::cvtColor(outMat, outMat, cv::COLOR_BGR2BGRA);`. Thank you!

Comment: M... so not sure how converting this "in-place" outMat -> outMat worked at all in the first place. That is a mystery.

Comment: It works well. Maybe OpenCV create new Mat itself, do convertation and then put result it to input Mat.